# Reconfiguring PHP with OpenSSL Extension on CentOS

Tags: openssl, php

Long time browser, first time poster!

I have a CentOS Dedicated server running just fine.

I'm trying to reconfigure PHP to include the OpenSSL extensions so I can use some of the Youtube API's.

I installed OpenSSL with yum, so it's in place on the server. I'm just now having trouble getting PHP to use it as an extension.

I got the latest PHP tarball, untarred, set my configure string (./configure) using the proper parameter for openssl (--with-openssl=/usr) and it checked out just fine.

I ran Make, then Make Install. I am getting hung up here. After it makes the PEAR config file it seems to quit. I guess I'm not sure, but it seems like there is a LOT more that should be happening. Here is a screenshot: http://www.evanfell.com/screencaps/6iamks.png

Restarting apache shows no change to the PHP running on the server.

Is there are PEAR issue killing the Install process? Or is there an other issue?

Thanks In Advance.

Happy to clarify and provide more info.

Comment: Is the Makefile incomplete?  Look for the `install` section.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't install php from a updated repository?
I use [remi-enterprise](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en).

Comment: Thanks for the response Lg.

I suppose because I don't know how to do it properly. I have a configure string with 30+ arguments for mysql, openssl, zend, etc, etc. How do I incorporate all of those settings when installing from the repository?

I'll do my research. Everything linux takes me forever! :)

Comment: Try to search on remi-enterprise repository the packages you need. At letter P, for example there is a lot of php packages: http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/i386/repoview/letter_p.group.html

Comment: You could add the remi repository and then check version packages by "yum info".

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys - I'll give the repository a shot. Hopefully I don't ruin it all.

Thanks.

Comment: If all that you need is only change/set some PHP build switches (without bump/update PHP version), you may download php SRPM from centos repo, alter the spec file and rebuild the package with 'rpmbuild'. Hope this helps to someone, because third-party repos aren't required for such simple task.